# How do I run an HBase instance on Windows 7?

Tags: java, windows, apache, hadoop

I followed the following instructions:

1. Download Hbase from https://hbase.apache.org/
2. Picked the suggested mirror and the most stable release.
3. I picked the bin tar tgz file
4. I extracted it on my Windows box
5. Found this:  http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/quickstart.html
6. I have cygwin already I set the
   config at hbase-site.xml to:
      `<configuration> 
       <property>
           <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
           <value>http://file:///ht_data/hbase/hbase</value>
         </property>
         <property>
           <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
           <value>/ht_data/hbase/zookeeper</value>
         </property>
   </configuration>`
7. Go to http://java.sun.com/javase/downloads/index.jsp
8. Install the one for windows x64
9. I added a new environment variable with
10. Name : JAVA_HOME
11. Value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141
12. From Windows cmd:
13. > cd "\hbase-1.2.6"
14. > bin\start-hbase.cmd

But I get:

```
`cygpath: can't convert empty path java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/regionserver/HRegionServer : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at http://java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at http://java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at http://java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at http://java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class:
```

org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" `

and

```
`cygpath: can't convert empty path java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/master/HMaster : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:632)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:616)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
at http://java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
at http://java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
at http://java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at http://java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.
```

Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" `

Do I need to install Hadoop to get this going at all? I just want to get a hello world going for now

I uncommented and modified the following on my hbase-env.sh FYI:

```
`export JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141"
export HBASE_CLASSPATH="<my path>\hbase-1.2.6\lib\zookeeper-3.4.6.jar"
export HBASE_OPTS="-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"`
```

Comment: Not sure about configuration on Windows, but if you want to directly start using hbase, I would recommend installing Cloudera quickstart VM. Its free and contains various hadoop ecosystem packages pre-configured.